# Can I make multiple join to the same table on different columns?

Tags: sql, linq

when you have a *"Shipment"* table with *DepartureId* and *DestinationId*. both Ids are from the *Location* table. how do you write a Linq (join) statement to get both the *DepartureName* and *DestinationName* from the Location table... Can I achieve that with primary-secondary relationship... good morning

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Morning, your mean is joining 2 Forign key on 1 primary key ?
u can refer on [Joining 2 Foreign key to 1 primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354957/sql-left-join-2-foreign-keys-to-1-primary-key/1354969).
Hope answered your question